# How to present the received (by UDP) data from node.js server in the client's browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

I have the simple node.js server that receives udp packages and prints them in the console:

```
var PORT            = 19777;
var MULTICAST_GROUP = "224.0.0.251";

var dgram = require("dgram");
var payload = new Buffer('A wild message appears');
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

client.on("message", function(message, rinfo) {
    console.log("received: ",message);
});
client.on("listening", function() {
    console.log("listening on ",client.address());

    client.setBroadcast(true);
    client.setTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastLoopback(true);
    client.addMembership(MULTICAST_GROUP);
    client.send(payload, 0, payload.length, PORT, MULTICAST_GROUP, function(err,bytes) {
        console.log("err: "+err+" bytes: "+bytes);
        // client.close();
    });
});
client.on("close", function() {
    console.log("closed");
});
client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("error: ",err);
});
client.bind(19777);
```

it works remotely on my server. I want to present the received data to each client that will turn on his browser and enter the address of my server. How could I do that?